# ACEGI Tag to Access Currently Logged In User Object

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, spring-security, struts-1

I have a legacy java webapp which uses Acegi Security. I am trying to remove all java scriplets from jsp pages. Is there any ACEGI tag which could be used to replace the following expression:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

The above expression returns the currently logged in user object. For example, I might have a JSP page which says "Hello, Bob your birthday is on Jan 1 1980." where the name "Bob" and the birthday are extracted from Bob's user object.

Note: I know that my Struts Action could declare the User object and initialize it to the value of the above code, but I would prefer to directly access the currently logged in user from the JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not generate your own taglib containing the missing tags?  It's very easy to do and you'll have all the code localized to a very tight area in case there are changes you want to make (like logging anytime a superuser logs in).

Answer (score 0):

There is the rather bizarre `authentication` tag in acegi.

```
<authz:authentication operation="name"/>
```

Will output the value of `getName` on the current principal.

It's not the most useful, but would be a good place to start if you implement your own version.